# Translating from aov to lmer or lme with three levels of nesting

Tags: r, anova, lme4-nlme

I have data from a split-plot (or repeated measure) experiment with three factors: A is random, B is fixed and nested within A, and C is fixed and nested within B. I can test for the effect of B, C and their interaction with the following code:

```
aov(x~B*C+Error(A/B/C))
```

I'd like to replicate this model using either lmer or lme. Numerous references online seem to indicate that `Error(A/B)` is analogous to `(1|A/B)` for lmer or `random=~1|A/B` for lme. Extending that logic, I tried:

```
lme(x~B*C,random=~1|A/B/C)
lmer(x~B*C+(1|A/B/C)
```

But these tables both gave different F values than the table generated with aov (. Can anyone tell me where I've gone wrong and how I can translate my initial aov model into either lme or lmer?

Thanks much!